# How can I turn the phone volume increase or decrease or even mute with react native

Tags: react-native, android-audiomanager

I need to mute the phone by pressing a button on the app. How to do it? I don't find any library for this!

Answer (score 2):

According to me you should make a native module for yourself because it typically needs two native services to hit i.e `setStreamVolume()` and `getStreamVolume()`.After updating the volume send event to javascript. Making native module helps you learn many things. In case you need help, i am available...

Code to mute the volume..

```
AudioManager am = 
    (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,1);
```

Cheers :)

Comment: I don't know anything of creating native module in case no knowledge of android app dev :( where to start?

Comment: updated the answer with native code , rest you learn and try .. :)

Comment: I have made more simpler for you... simply gave you the mute function..

Comment: Thanks! but i still don't know how to use this on React Native. I'll figure it out

Comment: you can achieve this by https://github.com/Tavernari/react-native-volume-controller

Comment: just pass the parameter for volume as 0 when you need to mute and hide the seek bar by giving null view... :)